# "Update Extensions Now" not working google chrome

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

`chrome://version/`

```
Google Chrome   29.0.1547.66 (Official Build 220848) m
OS  Windows 
Blink   537.36 (@156661)
JavaScript  V8 3.19.18.19
Flash   11,8,800,97
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Command Line    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Profile Path    C:\Users\nikumar\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
Variations  b0f8639e-3f4a17df
```

Here is my manifest.json ( Note the private IP in (192.168..) in my update_url. ):

```
{
   "key": "MIGfMA0GC...B",
   "name": "Test Plugin",
   "permissions": [ "http://*/", "https://*/" ],
   "plugins": [ {
      "path": "TestHost.dll",
      "public": true
   } ],
   "version": "1.1",
   "update_url": "http://192.168.35.120/crx.xml"
}
```

For some reason clicking on "Update extensions now" doesnt work. So my plugin is not getting updated. In wireshark i see no HTTP request going out at all.
I have few other extensions like adblock and gmail extensions etc, even those are not getting updated.

Only thing that i did different was that i manually added "update_url" in my manifest.json after installation of my test plugin. Should that work? If yes, what could be the reason that i don't see any GET request in wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

your extension crx file should have update_url in manifest.json. You need to add the update path manifest then repackage the extension.